# Animation on sencha touch 2 list item

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I have a list extending Ext.dataview.List.

I would like to play an animation in only one of the list items.

If it is triggered by the itemTap, it is easy, because the callback provides a third argument, I just run the animation on it. (I mean Ext.Anim.run).

But what if I need to animate the n-th element independently from the list, like triggered by a user tap on a separate button?

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer below fix your problem. If yes, then accept it, otherwise tell us what did not work and what error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list which has the following config :

```
xtype:'list',
cls: 'myList',
...
```

Then you can access its DOM element with :

```
var items = Ext.DomQuery.select('.myList .x-list-item');
```

It will returns all the items of the list with the cls 'myList' so be sure to have only one list with this class.

From there you can do whatever you want with it like hiding the second item :

```
items[1].style.display = 'none';
```

Hope this helped